# Multiple html data-* attributes and js function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, swap

The function is working good when I have only one `data-*` attribute declared, but if I have multiple `data-*` attributes for my product(product-image) the function is not working, in other words the product image is not showing up, it generates wrong `.src`.

In total I have 10 combinations of images (2 colors, each one with 5 different shapes).

I'm new to javascript/jquery. So will be very grateful for some help.

```
<div class="container">

    <h2>Product Page</h2>

    <div class="product-view">
        <img id="myimg" src="img/square_orange_img.jpg" width="372" height="511">
    </div>

    <div class="options">
        <p>Choose a Color:</p>
        <ul>
            <li><img class="colorbox" data-color="orange" style="background-color:orange;" onclick="changecolor(this)" alt=""></li>
            <li><img class="colorbox" data-color="purple" style="background-color:purple;" onclick="changecolor(this)" alt=""></li>
        </ul>

        <p>Select Shape:</p>
        <ul>
            <li><img class="shapes" data-shape="square" src="img/square-vertical.png" width="50" height="69" onclick="changeshape(this)" alt=""></li>
            <li><img class="shapes" data-shape="round" src="img/round-vertical.png" width="50" height="69" onclick="changeshape(this)" alt=""></li>
            <li><img class="shapes" data-shape="classic" src="img/classic-vertical.png" width="50" height="69" onclick="changeshape(this)" alt=""></li>
            <li><img class="shapes" data-shape="curved" src="img/curved-vertical.png" width="50" height="69" onclick="changeshape(this)" alt=""></li>
            <li><img class="shapes" data-shape="scallop" src="img/scallop-vertical.png" width="50" height="69" onclick="changeshape(this)" alt=""></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>

<script>
function changecolor(elem) {
    var color = elem.getAttribute("data-color");
    var shape = elem.getAttribute("data-shape");
    var newImageSrc = "img/" + shape + "_" + color + "_" + "img.jpg";
    document.getElementById("myimg").src = newImageSrc;
}
function changeshape(elem){
    var color = elem.getAttribute("data-color");
    var shape = elem.getAttribute("data-shape");
    var newImageSrc = "img/" + shape + "_" + color + "_" + "img.jpg";
    document.getElementById("myimg").src = newImageSrc;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some variables to keep the current `color` and `shape`. Then every time you change the color or the shape you'll update this variable and then load the image accordingly.

Trying to keep as much as possible your current code, you could just move your `color` and `shape` variables outside the functions. Then `changecolor` changes the current color and `changeshape` changes the current shape. You can initialize the `color` and `shape` variables to the initial values. In your case orange and square.

```
var color = 'orange';
var shape = 'square';
function changecolor(elem) {
    color = elem.getAttribute("data-color");
    var newImageSrc = "img/" + shape + "_" + color + "_" + "img.jpg";
    document.getElementById("myimg").src = newImageSrc;
}
function changeshape(elem){
    shape = elem.getAttribute("data-shape");
    var newImageSrc = "img/" + shape + "_" + color + "_" + "img.jpg";
    document.getElementById("myimg").src = newImageSrc;
}
```

See a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5s376v0h/). This won't work because the images are not available but should work in your environment.

Answer (score 1):

you can pass json to data attribute, do not use inline javascript, try to separate logic from markup

```
data-json='{"color": "blue", "shape": "circle"}'
```

or use jquery for simple access to the DOM

```
data-color="blue"
data-shape="circle" 

$("selector").data("color")
$("selector").data("shape")


<a href="#" id="elem" data-color="blue" data-shape="circle">click me!</a>

<script>

    $(function(){

        var el = $("#elem"),
            color, shape;

        el.click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();

            color = $(this).data("color");
            shape = $(this).data("shape");

            changeSomething(color, shape);
        });

        function changeSomething(color, shape){

            console.log(color + " " + shape);
        }

    });

</script>
```

or

```
<a href="#" id="elem" data-param='{"color": "blue", "shape": "circle"}'>click me!</a>

<script>

    $(function(){

        var el = $("#elem"),
            param = {};

        el.click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();

            param = $(this).data("param");

            changeSomething(param);
        });

        function changeSomething(param){

            console.log(param);
        }

    });

</script>
```

Comment: You mean to replace the data-* with data-json like you wrote? Sincerely I don't understand too much in all this stuff. Maybe you can show me a part of the code. Thank you in advance.